# Which tool to use for database (mssql) performance test? Write custom tool + profiler or Jmeter

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, jmeter, sql-server-profiler

I want to do performance testing for my database, so I need to simulate requests to database and also measure duration and other statistics.
my database is MS Sql Server 2005/8 and my server running ASP.NET under IIS

The tests I need to simulate require some flow logic that is not implemented in the database side, the testing tool needs to implement it.

For the purpose of this question, please ignore the impact of that flow logic and assume that it takes zero time and resources so it won't affect the results.

I'm considering 2 options:

1. **Write my own custom tool in C#**
   implement the flow logic in c#, and "just run the tests  in multi-threading" myself.
   I won't measure anything in the c# side, instead I'll use sql server profiler to measure database requests.
2. **Use Jmeter (or other equiv tool?)**
   implement the flow logic using jmeter (using standard components or sampler than can execute code). This way I won't have to handle the threads myself, jmeter will do it for me. In this case besides profiler I can also use Jmeter to measure database.

I prefer to first option, because writing my flow login is much more simple in C# comparing to jmeter built-in tools (logic controllers and etc..)

I have some experience in multi-threading and I know it can get complicated, but in this case, the tests are independent and don't share any data, so I won't have to deal much with locking.

I know jmeter is a great tool and it handle very well the time measuring, but in my case, I can use sql profiler.

**Do I underestimate the work and difficulties in managing my self the multi-threading?

Am I missing something else? Is There another option?**

Comment: Yes, you really underestimate the work and difficulties. Using existing tools will give you existing reporting, existing multi-threading, existing flexible test scenarios. A lot of work, really.

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

1. Use SQL Load Test. See http://sqlloadtest.codeplex.com/
2. Benchmark factory by Quest Software. See http://www.quest.com/benchmark-factory/
3. Use SQL Profiler to replay a trace that you have recorded. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189604.aspx OR  http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Replaying_a_Profiler_Trace
4. Use OStress (part of RMUtilities) See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944837

Answer (score 0):

You may use free WebAii Web Testing framework from Telerik to create web ui tests. 
You may also use it along with unit tests or even as part of unit tests.

But really, if you need to test the performance of the database then you may want to do it "as close" to the DB as possible, trying not to involve web UI.